# Sass - Repeating code, how can I make this more succinct

Tags: sass

I am creating helper classes that change the colour to predefined variables. For the most part the code is the same. I will be adding more specific selectors to this how can I make this easier to maintain?

```
.fg-text {
  color: $colorText;
  button, .button,
  input[type="button"],
  input[type="submit"],
  input[type="reset"],
  select {
    color: $colorText;
    border-color: $colorText;
  }
}
.fg-foreground {
  color: $colorForeground;
  button, .button,
  input[type="button"],
  input[type="submit"],
  input[type="reset"],
  select {
    color: $colorForeground;
    border-color: $colorForeground;
  }
}
.fg-alternate {
  color: $colorAlternate;
  button, .button,
  input[type="button"],
  input[type="submit"],
  input[type="reset"],
  select {
    color: $colorAlternate;
    border-color: $colorAlternate;
  }
}
.fg-background {
  color: $colorBackground;
  button, .button,
  input[type="button"],
  input[type="submit"],
  input[type="reset"],
  select {
    color: $colorBackground;
    border-color: $colorBackground;
  }
}
.fg-highlight {
  color: $colorHighlight;
  button, .button,
  input[type="button"],
  input[type="submit"],
  input[type="reset"],
  select {
    color: $colorHighlight;
    border-color: $colorHighlight;
  }
}
```

Comment: you can make a mixin.

Comment: Yeh I guess that's pretty obvious really. I've seen some people do complex stuff with grids and was probably overthinking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [@each directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive)

```
@each $name, $color in (text: $colorText, foreground: $colorForeground ...) {
  .fg-#{$name} {
    color: $color;
    button, .button,
    input[type="button"],
    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="reset"],
    select {
      color: $color;
      border-color: $color;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Additional note: You might be able to further simplify things by setting the color only on the `.fg-XYZ` element and use the value `currentColor` for the color and border-color of the buttons and form fields. See: https://css-tricks.com/currentcolor/

Answer (score 0):

I have condensed it to a mixin:

```
@mixin fg($name, $color) {
  .fg-#{$name} {
    color: $color;
    button, .button,
    input[type="button"],
    input[type="submit"],
    input[type="reset"],
    select {
      color: $color;
      border-color: $color;
    }
  }
}
@include fg(brand, $colorBrand);
@include fg(foreground, $colorForeground);
@include fg(background, $colorBackground);
@include fg(text, $colorText);
@include fg(alternate, $colorAlternate);
@include fg(highlight, $colorHighlight);
```